# Why am I unable to convert this audio file to base64?

Tags: javascript, cordova, base64

I'm building a Phonegap application that records audio then gets the audio file and converts it to base64. I then store that base64 data url in a variable and then use that variable to display the base64 data url in an alert box. Here's the code I have so far. It works perfectly on Android. On Android I get an alert message that says "data:audio/x-wav;base64,AAAAGGZ0ex" and so on. Obviously the string is a lot larger than that but I get the entire base64 data url on Android. On ios with the same code below, I get an alert message that says just "data:audio/wav;base64," with no data url. I literally just get an alert message that says this: "data:audio/wav;base64," exactly. Here is my code below. I'm using [Phonegap File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
   fileSystem.root.getFile("myaudio.wav", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);

}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);  
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    console.log("read success");
    console.log(evt.target.result);
    var thed = evt.target.result;
    alert(thed);            
        };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}


function recordAudio() {
    var src = "myaudio.wav";
    var mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();

    // Stop recording after 10 sec
    var recTime = 0;
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
        recTime = recTime + 1;
        setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
        if (recTime >= 7) {
            clearInterval(recInterval);
            mediaRec.stopRecord();

            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, function fail(){});

        }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the PhoneGap API, you need to mind OS specific quirks. You first need to confirm that the file is being created, and audio is written in that file. To do that, just play the file(The API has a [play()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.play)) and see if the audio plays.

Luckily I made a iOS specific PhoneGap application that recorded sound. It's on my GitHub [here](https://github.com/bhargavshah/iOS-Cordova-AudioRecorder/blob/recordm4a/www/index.html).

Your code is not recording sound at all, because on iOS before you make a Media instance you need to have a file already created. Refer my GitHub link, you'll get an idea.